# Upload with react generated pdf to google drive

Tags: reactjs, google-drive-api, react-pdf

In my application I am creating a pdf file using react-pdf.
I want the user to be able to upload this generated pdf to google drive..
i Have tried so far with with blob , but I had no succsess.
Happy for any help!! Thank you !

```
    const doc = <MyDocument req={props.data} />;
    const asPdf = pdf([]); 
    asPdf.updateContainer(doc);
    const blob = await asPdf.toBlob();

    
    const boundary = "foo_bar_baz";
    const delimiter = "\r\n--" + boundary + "\r\n";
    const close_delim = "\r\n--" + boundary + "--";
    var fileName = "mydocument.pdf";
    var fileData =  blob;
    var contentType = "application/pdf";
    var metadata = {
      name: fileName,
      mimeType: contentType,
    };



    var multipartRequestBody =
      delimiter +
      "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" +
      JSON.stringify(metadata) +
      delimiter +
      "Content-Type: " +
      contentType +
      "\r\n\r\n" +
      fileData +
      "\r\n" +
      close_delim;

    console.log(multipartRequestBody);
    var request = window.gapi.client.request({
      path: "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files",
      method: "POST",
      params: { uploadType: "multipart" },
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/related; boundary=" + boundary + "",
      },
      body: multipartRequestBody,
    });
    request.execute(function (file) {
      console.log(file);
      console.log(fileData)

    });
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `but I had no succsess`? If an error occurs, please show it. By the way, is `blob` of `const blob = await asPdf.toBlob();` the valid blob of PDF data?

Comment: By no success I mean that that a file was saved to google drive but the content was [object,blob].

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. As another question, is `blob` of `const blob = await asPdf.toBlob();` the valid blob of PDF data?

Comment: I am not sure. But this command renders the pdf correctly when downloading via download link.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the direction you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification point:

- In this case, I would like to propose to use the base64 data instead of the blob.

When this point is reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
var multipartRequestBody =
  delimiter +
  "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" +
  JSON.stringify(metadata) +
  delimiter +
  "Content-Type: " +
  contentType +
  "\r\n\r\n" +
  fileData +
  "\r\n" +
  close_delim;
```

To:

```
// I added below function.
const base64 = blob => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.onload = () => resolve(fr.result.split(",").pop());
  fr.onerror = () => reject(fr.error);
  fr.readAsDataURL(blob);
});
var multipartRequestBody =
  delimiter +
  "Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8\r\n\r\n" +
  JSON.stringify(metadata) +
  delimiter +
  "Content-Type: " + contentType + "\r\n" +
  'Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n' +  // Added
  await base64(blob) +  // Modified
  "\r\n" +
  close_delim;
```

- I used FileReader for converting the blob to the base64 data.

#### Note:

- In this modification, it supposes that `blob` of `const blob = await asPdf.toBlob();` is the valid blob of PDF data. Please be careful this.
- And, this answer supposes that you have already been able to upload a file using Drive API. Please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Comment: @alexander ciritsis Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By your cooperating, I could correctly understand about your question. Thank you, too.